# Low VLC framerate after seeking video

Tags: vlc-media-player

When playing video in VLC, all is good until I seek further into the video.  After the seek, the video plays at half the frame rate, and remains playing at that rate through the rest of the video.

This happens no matter what output module I use.

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

VLC 3.0.8, Windows 10 x64